# Why do I get a `failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img' error when updating?

Tags: boot, command-line, kernel, updates

I tried to update the Ubuntu but I'm receiving the follow error:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (3.2.0-24.39) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic to initrd.img: File exists
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
Setting up firefox (13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox ...
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Setting up firefox-globalmenu (13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up firefox-gnome-support (13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up firefox-locale-en (13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo rm /initrd.img` (its only a symlink)

followed by `sudo apt-get -f install linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic`